# Errors due to static inline version of a earlier non-static non-inline function

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have a function which is initially declared in a header file my.h to have external linkage(no storage class specified)

```
int myfunc(int);
```

And this function definition and it's call is present in source file my.c
my.c includes my.h

This all is fine.

But now I wanted to make this function myfunc inline 
So I declare a new prototype in my.c

as

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) static inline  int myfunc(int)
```

and define it so in same function as before,

as expected I keep getting an error saying

> static declaration of 'myfunc' follows non-static declaration

I need to keep the non-static,non-inline version of this function for a C reference version of code , and the static inline version for a optimized version of the code.

How can I work around this problem , as I need a static declaration of that function., within this existing source/header files setup I have

One way is I change the name of the static inline function to myfuncinline and work with it!

But is there any way within current setup.

Comment: Can you explain what you are tring to do in more detail, IDK what you are talking about with wanting a different version for "reference version" etc.

Comment: Then remove `static`.

Answer (score 2):

A function defined with static storage-class specifier has internal linkage. You cannot refer to it outside that translation unit.

If you cannot change the declaration of myfunc in the header, then write two 
functions in the source file. One called myfuncreal, which does all the work and is defined with static inline:

```
__attribute__((always_inline)) static inline  int myfuncreal(int a)
{
     //uses parameter a and returns the result
}
```

And the other called myreal that wraps around myfuncreal, defined as:

```
int myfunc(int a)
{
    return myfuncreal(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Maybe i was unclear in OP. The static inline version is a platform specific version which ha some constructs valid only on a certain target platform e.g. say ARM. and other version being the plain C reference code without any platform specific constructs. So if I wrap as u say, the C reference version will fail to build/link.

Comment: @goldenmean You should use preprocessor directives for that.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#ifndef DEBUG
static inline
#endif
int myfunc(int);
```

Assuming DEBUG is defined in your debug builds but not in your optimized builds. Note that this example is for a declaration in a .c file or a definition in a .h file; for a declaration in a .h *and* a definition in a .c do

```c
/* foo.h */
#ifdef DEBUG
int myfunc(int);
#endif

/* foo.c */
#ifndef DEBUG
static inline int myfunc(int);
#endif
/* code that uses myfunc() */
#ifndef DEBUG
static inline
#endif
int myfunc(int) {/* definition */}
```

Comment: First of all, you did not explain anything. Second of all, this will cause the same problem if `DEBUG` is NOT defined.

Comment: My solution is much the same as yours, except it has the advantage of being readable and not polluting the namespace. And I *said* this is under the assumption that DEBUG is defined for non-optimized builds, which any reasonable compiler does. It could be replaced with RELEASE or whatever relevant macro there might be should that not be the case. Btw, the tactic of trying to raise your visibility by downvoting answers other than your own the second they're posted is perhaps a sign you need an internet break.